# Parse JSON in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I am new to Objective-C, and JSON so I am confused on how to do this. I have looked up tutorials, and made sure my JSON is valid.

I have a SQL server database that I am trying to access by parsing JSON. I have checked to make sure my JSON is valid. Whenever I attempt to parse the JSON is Objective-C, however, it always returns null.

Here is my JSON:

```
[
{
    "ID": 1,
    "Username": "Cray",
    "Password": "fake",
    "Active": 0,
    "LastLogin": null
}
]
```

Here is my Objective-C code:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://quacknasty.com/service.php"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;

NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"test%@", json);
```

`json` always returns null when I do the `NSLog`

Comment: You see that parm called "error".  It has a purpose.  if the result from NSJSONSerialization is nil, use NSLog to print out "error":  `NSLog(@"JSON error = %@", error);`

Comment: I tried to access: http://quacknasty.com/service.php  using Google Chrome browser, it returned an empty []. Are you sure your server returns some JSON? By the way, in the above code, your urlString is redundant, you can simply put [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://....."]; instead of [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]; since your urlString variable can be reduced to a string literal @"http://....";

Comment: @Zhang: Technically `[]` is absolutely valid JSON! He did change his server code since yesterday, see my answer, there is the original API response. @user3871044: Did my answer solve your problems? Then please remember to accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy one: Open the URL in a browser. You will see that you don't have valid JSON:

```
Conneection established. 
[{"ID":1,"Username":"Cray","Password":"fake","Active":0,"LastLogin":null}]
```

You have to remove the echo of `Connection established.\n`

**EDIT I:** You have to use `NSArray` as root object, because the JSON string starts with `[]`

**EDIT II:** Additionally you should set the correct HTTP Header fields as follows:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Request to thi URL. Response is :

```
Conneection established. 
<br />[{"ID":1,"Username":"Cray","Password":"fake","Active":0,"LastLogin":null}]
```

It's not json format